# NSTokenField tokens disappear when mouse leaves non-selected NSTokenField

Tags: cocoa, nstokenfield

Weird UI bug that is exactly what is reported at this link:

http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg53307.html

The tokens in my NSTokenField disappear if I move the mouse into the non selected/currently editing field and then start moving the mouse out.

The tokens just flicker away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it was because I had a core animation backing layer checked within the xib that contained my nstokenfields... very weird.  Ill probably report to Apple on this buggy bug.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I had the same bug, but it wasn't because of CA, but because I had a custom string formatter attached to it, which was clearly messing up the tokens in some way. Just for the record.